# Apache2 NTLM not working with reverse proxy load balancer

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

We're working on setting up load balancing between two Apache servers on two different Windows Server 2012 machines (let's call them VmA and VmB), at the present we use the `mod_authnz_sspi` to authenticate users using Windows Authentication. `VmA` hosts the load balancer, and a secondary HTTP server to serve requests, `VmB` just hosts a HTTP server.

The issue we're having is that it does not automatically pass credentials through to the secondary server and it will always ask to enter credentials (important to note, if you do enter credentials it will work, however this isn't an option for our environment). Also, if we *disable* `VmB` in the server balancing and only have `VmA` in the balancer, it works without a hitch. It only asks for credentials when working as a proxy between VMs.

Here is my `httpd.conf` file for reference.

```
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
        BalancerMember "http://VmAhostname:8080"
        BalancerMember "http://VmBhostname:80"
</Proxy>

KeepAlive On

SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled
SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On

ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass               "/" "balancer://mycluster/"
ProxyPassReverse        "/" "balancer://mycluster/"
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Could be something to do with `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath`. Look [here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/901528) for more details. Look [here in the official docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiepath) as well.

Comment: Hey mate thanks for the comment, gave this a go and unfortunately having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so we worked it out eventually. Essentially the best course is to remove NTLM auth from the request servers and only enable auth on the balance loading server. Then, have the reverse proxy server add a request header with the auth details.

If you do this you will **need** to secure the request servers to only allow traffic from the reverse proxy server, or else anybody could header inject a username.

After removing auth from the request servers just add this to the reverse proxy server:

`RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}`

And that should do it!